# Best practice for adding a custom field in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a custom field located in my `/app/models.py` . My question is...

What is the best practice here. Should I have a separate file i.e. `customField.py` and import to the `models.py`, or should it be all in the same `models.py` file?
best practice

```
class HibernateBooleanField(models.BooleanField):

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "HibernateBooleanField"

    def db_type(self):
        return 'bit(1)'

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in (True, False): return value
        if value in ('t', 'True', '1', '\x01'): return True
        if value in ('f', 'False', '0', '\x00'): return False

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return 0x01 if value else 0x00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put any custom fields of yours in a separate `fields.py`.

Have a look at some apps in `django.contrib`, most have a generic structure of a single `models.py`, `fields.py`, `views.py`, `middleware.py` etc.

Following the standard means that your app can be picked up by anyone familiar with the django framework with ease.

Comment: I like this idea as the import makes sense i.e. from app.fields import customBooleanField

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recomend to have everything in one `models.py` file. I like to create separate packages for models, fields and views, which then contain additional modules. I think it's one of the best solutions for code structure and readability of Django application. 
It looks like this:

```
/app
  /models
     /__init__.py
     /model1.py
     /model2.py
  /fields
     /__init__.py
     /custom_field1.py
     /custom_field2.py
  /views
     /__init__.py
     /page1.py
     /page2.py
```

Comment: so even in their own folder? are you also saying you split each of your models out i.e. classes?

Comment: Yes, I think it's more readable and looks more clean. I like to have less than 150/200 lines of code in one file and that is not usualy possible with more than one class.

Comment: This is complete overkill for an app with any complexity. If your app has 10 models you would have a separate file for each one?

Comment: I would try to separate them, create or move them to another application. If it would not be possible then I would rather have separate 10 files than 10 models/classes in one file.

Comment: the only issue I have with above is that when I import them into my models it wont make as much sense i.e. from app.fields.custom1 import custom1. still gives me something to think about.

Comment: @Spike you can import all fields in `__init__.py` in fields package and then it's enough to write `from app.fields import custom1`